# Missing \endcsname inserted when drawing tikz automata

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I am using the example provided [here](https://www3.nd.edu/~dchiang/teaching/theory/2018/www/tikz_tutorial.pdf), and the code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}       
\tikzset{node distance=2.5cm, 
         every state/.style={
          semithick,fill=gray!10},
          initial text={}, 
          double distance=2pt, 
          every edge/.style={
          draw, ->,>=stealth’, 
          auto,semithick}}
\let\epsilon\varepsilon


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state, initial] (q1) {$q_1$};
\node[state, accepting, right of=q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
\node[state, right of=q2] (q3) {$q_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I keep getting "missing \endcsname inserted" error, please help.

Comment: The `’` after `>=stealth` is a nonstandard character. If you replace it by `'` your code runs through.

Comment: @marmot Thanks!!!

Comment: @marmot How about detokenizing the arrow tip? https://github.com/hmenke/pgf/commit/bcced354310c2967c72897efd321910c85f258a5